# Anchor to different headers with same ID?

Tags: php, wordpress, html, hyperlink

I have a wordpress site that generates a header on multiple places on a single page.

I would like for the top menu to anchor down to these headers using conventional means i.e:

```
<a href=#Header1>Header</a>
```

However I do not know how to do this. Looking into the code I can see it generates the following:

```
return sprintf( '<h2 class="wc-nested-category-layout-category-title">%s</h2>', $link );
```

so I then thought to add a ID:

```
return sprintf( '<h2 id="IdToGoHere" class="wc-nested-category-layout-category-title">%s</h2>', $link );
```

But of course then I know all the headers will have the same ID which is not good practice. Is there a way to create a different ID per header? Or could the header look for each one like:

```
<a href=#Header(1)>Header 1</a>
<a href=#Header(2)>Header 2</a>
<a href=#Header(3)>Header 3</a>
```

Thank you for your time

Comment: The way to do this would be to pass a number to your sprintf() function - can we see the full code that this features in - assuming its a loop but better to see than guess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you need header elements with incremental IDs every time you can do something like this:

```
static $i = 1;
return sprintf( '<h2 id="Header%d" class="wc-nested-category-layout-category-title">%s</h2>', $i++, $link );
```

But it's better to pass it as an argument.

Comment: That is exactly what I was after, thank you for such a quick reply